# Format a date at a given precision

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

Formatting dates in JavasScript has been made really easy through moment.js. But I was wondering if there is a simple way to format a date for a given precision (with or without this library). Say:

```
var date = new Date();
assert.equal(format(date, 'days'), '2015-02-13')
assert.equal(format(date, 'minutes'), '2015-02-13 11:14')
```

I can easily imagine a switch case for the different cases, and can understand the output formats are standard only in my point of view, but still.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object you can make your own formatter as you please. Would something like this suffice?

```
var getFullDate = function(d) {
  var day = d.getDate();
  day = day < 10 ? '0' + day : day;

  var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
  month = month < 10 ? '0' + month : month;
  return d.getFullYear() + '-' + month + '-' + day;
}

var getHoursAndMinutes = function(d) {
  var minutes = d.getMinutes()
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;

  var hours = d.getHours()
  hours = hours < 10 ? '0' + hours : hours;
  return hours + ':' + minutes;
}

var format = function(d, fmt) {
  switch(fmt){
    case 'minutes': return getFullDate(d) + ' ' +  getHoursAndMinutes(d);
    case 'days': return getFullDate(d);
  }
}
```

Comment: It will suffice, but I was more looking for already existing methods ;-)